# Which theme used by website?

Tags: web-services

I want to develop my own website.  and use theme same as another website. Please let me know which theme is running on this website. Please just go through http://protechhub.com

Answer (score 0):

http://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054 Here you go. I think it's this one. Make sure to check the demo link.

Comment: Thanks. How did u do that?

Comment: If you look up the source code, "head" section, all "link" tags which include css are named "bridge". So I searched on google "bridge theme" and found what I gave you. By the way I think you should use themes only when you have a full understanding at making your own themes and consider the disadvantages: a themed website looses its originality even though you'll be faster at developing it. Making websites is an art of creativity and expression. I know "already complete" themes may seem appealing but in my personal experience a "hand made" website gives more satisfaction. : - )